# Ifstream to read "Name" column with multiple spaces in name c++

Tags: c++, ifstream

I am trying to read a file using ifstream in c++. The file has 5 columns and last column is the name column which contains the name with multiple spaces in the name. Some names have 1 and some have 2 spaces.

I want to read the name in a single variable instead of multiple ones.
I have used :

```
while (infile >> recordDate >> relativeHumidity >> airTemp >> tempUnit >> name1 >> name2 >>> name3){}
```

Above code works fine for the names having 2 spaces but when it reads the line which has a name with one space the ***name3*** varialble stores the first value of next line.

```
Date        RelativeHumidity        Air Temp     Units      Meteorologist Name
5/13/2009        1.096000          34.630000        C        D. Bernoulli
7/1/1903        0.313000           77.470000        f        Sir C. Wren
```

Comment: Instead of using a plain text file (assuming you are), wouldn't it be much easier to use a binary file and store an object of data into the file? This will make your task a whole lot easier. Just make a class with all the properties in your file and then you can store and retrieve an entire row into one object

Comment: I am reading data from a .dat file. And I cannot use classes at this level. 
I can only use ifstream to read the file and process  the values and output on console.

Answer (score 3):

Use `getline` to read to the end of line, that way you only need one variable.

```
while ((inFile >> recordDate >> relativeHumidity >> airTemp >> tempUnit) && 
    std::getline(inFile, name))
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like the following:

```
while (infile)
{
        infile >> recordDate >> relativeHumidity >> airTemp >> tempUnit;
        getline(infile, name);
        const auto trim = [](const auto& s) {
            return s.substr(
                s.find_first_not_of(' ', 0),
                s.find_last_not_of(' ', 0)
            );
        };
        name = trim(name);
}
```

Comment: In this code, you process input without checking whether it succeeded. Also, even if the input is valid, the last iteration will try to read and process non-existent line (this will clear unsuccessfully read variables, but it still likely is not what is wanted). It's better to perform input in the `while` condition and let stream conversion to `bool` check whether input was successful (as in john's answer). Same for `getline`.

Comment: I'm not sure to get it. How does `while(stream >> a >> b) { }` (which I think can be rewritten into `do { stream >> a >> b; } while(stream)`) differ from `while(stream) { stream >> a >> b; }` in terms of error checking and last iteration?

Comment: Ok. I think I get it. I think misunderstood the post. I assumed processing for each line would be added in the while block. But if you want to parse the complete file and only keep the results for the last line yeah, you're right my solution does not work.

Comment: In `while (stream >> a >> b) { process(a, b); }` you can't process wrong `a` or `b` values (which will be "cleared" by `operator>>` in some way depending on type, e.g. integers set to 0) if the read was failed (e.g. due to attempt to read after EOF is reached), because failbit is set and conversion done by `operator bool` for the stream (*after* input) returns `false`, so loop body is not entered. For `while (stream) { stream >> a >> b; process(a, b); }` you check stream validity *before* read, so if read is unsuccessull, it's not detected in time and `process` gets wrong values.